# jQuery fire mouseover event one by one

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <div class="hover-tile">
        <div class="base"><img src="/images/hovtile/1.png" /></div>
        <div class="cover"><img src="/images/hovtile/1-c.png" /></div>
        <div class="hover"><img src="/images/hovtile/1-h.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <div class="hover-tile">
        <div class="base"><img src="/images/hovtile/2.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="cover"><img src="/images/hovtile/2-c.png" /></div>
        <div class="hover"><img src="/images/hovtile/2-h.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <div class="hover-tile">
        <div class="base"><img src="/images/hovtile/3.png" /></div>
        <div class="cover"><img src="/images/hovtile/3-c.png" /></div>
        <div class="hover"><img src="/images/hovtile/3-h.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user hovers his mouse on the image it shows another image. I want to retain this functionality and add a automatic mouseover event which does this one by one .

I tried the following code . It fires the mouseover for all the images simultaneously. I want it to happen one by one. Also it should return to origianl state . How can I achieve this ? and the same periodically.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var delay=0;
    $('.base').each(function(i, obj) {

        $(this).delay(delay).trigger("mouseover");
            delay += 500;
    });
});
```

The user action hover is implemented by

```
$('.hover-tile').hover(function(e){
    $(this).children('.hover').fadeIn(350);
},function() {
    $(this).children('.hover').fadeOut(250);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's all at once? 500ms delay isn't that long between each.

Comment: made it 2000 stil it does it for all together.

Comment: @rrmo What do you mean show another image? So is it like show 1.png first, then 1-c.png and then 1-h.png or show first .hover-tile, and then the next one and so on.

Comment: yes by default its 1.png , i want to automatically show 1-h.png on mouseover event and 1.png on mouseout event . The delay should be about 2 seconds

Comment: What about 1-c.png? Could you post your mouseover handler so I can understand what you are doing?

Comment: no Iam not using 1-c.png. I dont have a mouseover  handler. Currently its all in CSS on hover it changes to class "hover" . I want to automate this functionality .

Comment: @rrmo I think, You are mixing JavaScript event with CSS hover. It doesn't work like that, CSS `:hover` can be triggered only by user action and not from JavaScript.

Comment: Yes @Vega CSS hover is triggered by user action . I also want to do the same via javascript for each image one by one.

Comment: @Vega I have added the current js for hover. Sorry got your point now

Comment: Isn't `.delay()` only reserved for animation queues? The mouseover event is not an animation queue, that's why all events are triggered at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) specifies that the `delay()` function only has an effect on events making use of the effects queue. There is no mention specifying the `trigger()` function makes use of it. Therefore, all of your mouseover triggers are fired consecutively, but without waiting your 500ms.

You could maybe do something like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var delay=0;
    $('.base').each(function(i, obj) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(obj).trigger('mouseover');
        }, delay);
        delay += 500;
    });
});
```